# View categories list with posts under the categories, which have status='published' in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a project, which have below models and views:

Models:

```
class InformationCategory(models.Model):
    # fileds here

class InformationPost(models.Model):
    informations = models.ForeignKey(InformationCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="information_posts" )

    # other fields here
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
```

Views

```
def getInformed(request):
    template = 'getinformed/information-cat-list.html'

    categories = InformationCategory.objects.filter(Available=True)
    args = {
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, template, args)
```

Template

```
{% for cat in categories %}
<h2 class="catTitle">  {{cat.Title}}  </h2>
<ol class="itemTitle">
    {% for post in cat.information_posts.all %}
        <li><a href="{{post.geturl}}">{{post.Title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to view the list of all categories, and the posts under each category, but the posts' status should be status=’published’. The code above shows all  categories with all posts under those categories, but the problem is that I do not want to show the posts that have status=’draft’. I mean below:

```
CATEG 1     
    Post 1  
    Post 2  
    Post 3 (should be hidden, because status=’draft’ not published).
```

How can I solve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Views:

```
def getInformed(request):
    template = 'getinformed/information-cat-list.html'

    categories = InformationCategory.objects.filter(Available=True)
    informationposts = InformationPost.objects.filter(informations__in = categories, status = 'published')
    args = {
        'categories': categories, 'informationposts': informationposts
    }
    return render(request, template, args)
```

Template:

```
{% for cat in categories %}
<h2 class="catTitle">  {{cat.Title}}  </h2>
<ol class="itemTitle">
    {% for post in informationposts %}
    {% if cat == post.informations%}
        <li><a href="{{post.geturl}}">{{post.Title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it works, thank you for your comment, but it seems too complicated in compare the one I posted as answer. Seems there is possibility to filter inside the template as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is possible to filter inside a template.
The below way, the filtering is done at the database level using the Django ORM, which can be more efficient than filtering in the template. This keeps your template clean and focused on presentation logic, while the data retrieval logic is handled in the view and the ORM.

```
{% for cat in categories %}
    <h2 class="catTitle">  {{cat.Title}}  </h2>
    <ol class="itemTitle">
        {% for post in cat.information_posts.filter(status='published') %}
            <li><a href="{{post.geturl}}">{{post.Title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endfor %}
```

I did not change my view even.